# Malformed HTML while sending CLOB as body to UTL_SMTP

Tags: html, oracle, email, plsql, smtp

I have a requirement to send an Email from an Oracle database.
This will be rather long with a table contains more than 1k rows.

The basic Pl/SQL code is as follows -

```
PIVARHTMLMSG   CLOB;
LNUMSTART NUMBER := 1;
LNUMCHUNK NUMBER := 1900;
I NUMBER := 0;

PIVARHTMLMSG := '<HTML><BODY><P>Some Heading</P><TABLE BORDER="1"><TR><TD>ID</TD><TD>NAME</TD><TD>EMAIL</TD></TR>';

WHILE (TRUE)
LOOP
    PIVARHTMLMSG := PIVARHTMLMSG || '<TR><TD>999999</TD><TD>TEST TEST TEST</TD><TD>TEST.TEST@TEST.COM</TD></TR>';
    I := I + 1;
    IF I > 1000 THEN
        EXIT;
    END IF;        
END LOOP;

WHILE LNUMSTART < NVL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(PIVARHTMLMSG), 0) LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(lMailConn,DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(PIVARHTMLMSG,LNUMCHUNK,LNUMSTART));
    LNUMSTART := LNUMSTART + LNUMCHUNK;  
    LNUMCHUNK := LEAST(LNUMCHUNK,DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(PIVARHTMLMSG) -LNUMCHUNK);
END LOOP;
```

The email is rendered as follows -

[image]

What could be possible reason for such a behavior ?

Comment: Please show your full code which sends the mail.

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide the most important stuff, e.i. calls of `UTL_SMTP` procedures.

Have a look at my procedure to send mail:

```
SUBTYPE T_MAIL_PRIORITY IS INTEGER;
PRIORITY_HIGH           CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
PRIORITY_NORMAL         CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
PRIORITY_LOW            CONSTANT INTEGER := 5;

PROCEDURE SendMail(
    Subject IN VARCHAR2, 
    Message IN OUT CLOB, 
    ToMail IN VARCHAR2,   
    FromMail IN VARCHAR2, FromName IN VARCHAR2,
    Attachment IN OUT CLOB, FileName IN VARCHAR2,
    Priority IN T_MAIL_PRIORITY) IS

    MIME_BOUNDARY           CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := '====Multipart.Boundary.689464861147414354====';
    MIME_MIXED              CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'multipart/mixed;';
    MIME_TEXT               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'text/plain;';
    MIME_HTML               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'text/html;';  

    con UTL_SMTP.connection;
    ret UTL_SMTP.reply;
    Charset VARCHAR2(20);

    ClobLen PLS_INTEGER;
    amount BINARY_INTEGER := 8192;
    buffer VARCHAR2(16384);
    offset PLS_INTEGER := 1;
    isHTML BOOLEAN := REGEXP_LIKE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(Message, 1000, 1), '<(html)|(body)', 'i');

BEGIN

    SELECT UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE)
    INTO Charset
    FROM nls_database_parameters
    WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

    -- setup mail header
    con := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION('mailhost', 25);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.helo(con, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'DB_DOMAIN'));
    ret := UTL_SMTP.Mail(con, FromMail);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.rcpt(con, ToMail);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.open_data(con);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'From: "'||FromName||'" <'||FromMail||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'To: '||ToMail||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Date: '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss TZHTZM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')||UTL_TCP.CRLF);      
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Subject: '||Subject||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'X-Priority: '||Priority||UTL_TCP.CRLF);

    IF Attachment IS NOT NULL AND FileName IS NOT NULL THEN
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Mime-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-Type: '||MIME_MIXED||' boundary="'||MIME_BOUNDARY||'"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'This is a multipart message in MIME format.' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, '--'||MIME_BOUNDARY || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    IF isHTML THEN
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-type: '||MIME_HTML||' charset='||Charset || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    ELSE 
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-type: '||MIME_TEXT||' charset='||Charset || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    -- Mail Body
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Message);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN offset > ClobLen;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(Message, amount, offset, BUFFER);
        UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(con, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(BUFFER));
        offset := offset + amount;
    END LOOP;   
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);

    IF Attachment IS NOT NULL AND FileName IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- Mail Attachment
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, '--'||MIME_BOUNDARY || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-Type: '||MIME_TEXT||' name="'||Filename||'"'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'||Filename||'"'|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);

        offset := 1;
        ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Attachment);
        LOOP
            EXIT WHEN offset > ClobLen;
            DBMS_LOB.READ(Attachment, amount, offset, BUFFER);
            UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(con, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(BUFFER));
            offset := offset + amount;
        END LOOP;
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, '--'||MIME_BOUNDARY||'--' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;

    -- finish mail
    ret := UTL_SMTP.close_data(con);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.quit(con);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR OR UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
        UTL_SMTP.quit(con);
        RAISE;
END SendMail;
```

Don't miss "empty" `UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);` calls, they are required for proper outline of your mail.

Also line `UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'This is a multipart message in MIME format.' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);` looks not relevant - it is relevant for proper output!

Here the result of my test using your message.

[image]

Comment: No luck, still the same output as in the screenshot.

Comment: No need for the actual code, the problem lies within Outlook Mail server and not in Oracle. Refer this link for more info. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448

Comment: Strange, some time ago I had the same problem with wrongly formatted mails but this procedure solved it. Maybe consider to add the HTML document as attachment, see my updated procedure.

Comment: Requirement is for html mail, can't send it as attachment. Anyways thank for your inputs.